# Nativescript Angular navigate and backToPreviousPage stop working

Tags: angular, nativescript

my app has 4 pages: Login -> Home -> Order -> Finish

From Login to Home I navigate with clearHistory true.
From Home to Order I navigate with clearHistory false.
From Order to Finish I navigate with clearHistory false.

If I only move between Home and Order the navigation and back button works fine, but if I navigate from Order to Finish and go back from Finish to Order with backToPreviousPage, all navigation stop working.

Commands navigate and backToPreviousPage stop working. No errors and the applications works in Order page without problem but back button or finish button with navigation commands are not working.

I've debugged the app and the command navigate or backToPreviousPage are called but no result from them.

I'm working with page-router-outlet

ROUTING FILE:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

import { GuardService } from './services/guard.service'

import { LoginComponent } from '~/pages/login/login.component';
import { PhrasesComponent } from '~/pages/phrases/phrases.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '~/pages/home/home.component';
import { OrderComponent } from '~/pages/order/order.component';
import { FinishComponent } from '~/pages/finish/finish.component';
import { PendingComponent } from '~/pages/pending/pending.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'phrases', component: PhrasesComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
    { path: 'order/:id', component: OrderComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
    { path: "finish/:id", component: FinishComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] },
    { path: "pending/:id", component: PendingComponent, canActivate: [GuardService] }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Any idea?
Regards

Comment: can you please post your routing file?

Comment: This is the routing file (edited)

Comment: looks like it might be an issue with your auth guard

Comment: Did you try `routerExtenstions.back()` instead?

Comment: Yes with the same result as backToPreviousPage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in an app code hidden error, not showed at any time in console. After this error the app navigations stop working.

Thanks to all for the help!!